# XSLT code for xml transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I want xml transformation using xslt. Here is the xml that needs to be transformed:

This fails because there is missing namespace for the attribute value "xsi:type" which is "Insert", I want it as "ns:Insert". I tried using online xsl transformer(http://www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation/#.WrtA4S5uZEQ), it works fine there, but once I put it in my code. I do not get the desired prefix. Any reason for that ??

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I have edited the question to wrap the xml under soap envelope, thats the full xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to add `xmlns:v1="http://stil.dk/ipung/services/synclokationer/v1.0"`
to your source XML, otherwise it was not well-formed.

I used the below script (slightly modified your version):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:v1="http://stil.dk/ipung/services/synclokationer/v1.0"
    xmlns:ns="http://www.logica.com/veu/syncSkole/dto/Lokationer"
    exclude-result-prefixes="v1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:com="http://www.logica.com/veu/syncSkole/dto/common">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}"><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="comment() | text() | processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="v1:Lokation">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:attribute name="xsi:type">
                <xsl:value-of select="translate(@xsi:type, 'v1', 'ns')" />
             </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="v1:Modtager | v1:ModtagerSystemID |
        v1:ModtagerSystemTransaktionsID | v1:Afsendelsestidspunkt |
        v1:BeskedID | v1:InstNr">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}"
            namespace="http://www.logica.com/veu/syncSkole/dto/common">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Caution: Namespace different than above -->
    <xsl:template match="v1:syncLokationer">
        <xsl:element name="ns:{local-name()}"
            namespace="http://www.logica.com/veu/syncSkole/dto/Lokationer">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Under www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation I got `Lokation` element as follows:

```
<Lokation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:type="ns:Insert">
```

So `xsi:type` attribute has value `ns:Insert`, just as you expected.

### Edit:

As *Parfait* proposed, I modified the script to eliminate repeating templates,
differing only in *match* attribute.

Comment: The repeating templates can be combined with pipe delimiter, `|`.

Comment: *Parfait* is right. Initially I missed that a number of your templates have **the same** content, they differ only in *match* attribute. So you can use **only one** such template, matching a number of tag names, separated with a "|".